# Is there a way to get an EntityQuery from an OData uri

Tags: breeze

In my application, I use the Odata Uri generated by breeze as a deep linked url.

Is there a way to get the reverse of this odata query, which is the breeze.EntityQuery that was originally used to build this uri?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on your larger purpose. What would you do if you could translate an OData URI into an `EntityQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not for the OData URI format.

However, the new [JSON uri format](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-using-json) supported by breeze, is completely reversible.  If you are willing to switch to that, you will be able to get the breeze.EntityQuery from the JSON that is serialized on the URI.

I'm not sure how that would mess up your deep linking.

Comment: I think you'd be exchanging one inscrutable link (the OData URI) for another (the JSON URI). Do you care that the URL is human readable?  OTOH, the JSON URI isn't really an option if your server doesn't understand it.

Comment: This is perfect. I just needed a way to get the EntityQuery back from something. My server speaks OData so I will deep link with the JSON string instead and re-execute the OData query. The query is dynamically built from the UI so I needed a way to rebuild the UI based on that query. That will do the trick! Thanks!